# What can I do after a corpse despawns?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing Skyrim on the xbox-360.

I killed Vokun and left I haven't been to the place for a few days also, Lydia died and I can't find either one of them I didn't get the chance to loot Vokun and Lydia despawned. What do I do? Please tell me.

Comment: since you are on the xbox you are SOL I'm afraid...

Comment: The Dragon Priest thread of prophecy has been severed.

Answer (score 3):

When named people die they will generally lay around for a few days and then be interred with all of their possessions they had on them. If this happened you can go to the crypts in the town where they were from, if it has one, and see if you can find them in there. For example Lydia should be in the crypts in Whiterun located up by the temple of Mara. If she is not in there however then the goods are gone.